# How to call task CreateNew()/ ContinueWith() periodically?

Tags: multithreading

I'm new to TPL and .net 4. I'm kind of stuck to implement the following multithread design.

What I want to do is to check serial ports and send out data then update the list box on UI(WPF), then wait for 1 sec and do that once again.

What I have done is:

```
//from WPF UI thread
var uiThreadTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var bgTask = Task<MonitorStatus>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     MonitorStatus status = new MonitorStatus();

    //some time consuming job on serial ports

    return status;
});

bgTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    MonitorStatus status = task.Result;

    //update the list box

}, uiThreadTaskScheduler);
```

What I love most is StartNew() and ContinueWith(): it starts to do some time consuming job in anther thread and come back to UI thread with task.Result and I can update the UI. No synchronization object explicitly!

But how can I keep this run again and again after a 1 sec time interval? 
I want to re-run the whole thing at the last code in ContinueWith(), so that it never stops. but how?

Another solution in my mind is to use threading.timer, but its thread is running in other thread than UI thread, which is not as convenient as ContinueWith().

Comment: Use `Task.Delay(1000)` to create a task that completes after 1 second. But really I would just use a `Timer` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I finally choose to use DispatcherTimer and in its callback I create a new task.